# Can anyone help explain these diagrams related to non planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So,

Kuratowski theorem tells us that a graph G is planar iff it does not contain a $K_{5}$ or $K_{3,3}$ minor,

[image]

Is non planar because

[image]

I am not really sure how to understand the red drawing. It says it  shows a $K_{3,3}$ minor. But is it doing some sort of edge/vertex deletions? What would the bipartition be?

Also,

[image]

is planar because it has a planar drawing. So isnt the drawing with vertex g removed the planar graph?

So basically, I am generally confused in the difference between having a minor and a subdivison , and which implies the other.

I know that a subgraph of a planar graph is planar, and if a subgraph is non planar then the graph is non planar. But a subgraph can be planar while the original graph is still non planar, I guess that is what is showcased in this example.

But mostly I am confused about the diagram and what the red represents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contracting the two red edges leaves $K_5$, showing that the graph is not planar.

We can find a $K_{3,3}$ minor by contracting the bottom edge $ef$. One side of the partition of the $K_{3,3}$ minor is $\{a,b,g\}$.